# Groovy Truth: string to boolean inconsistency?

Tags: groovy

In groovy:

```
println 'test' as Boolean //true
println 'test'.toBoolean() //false
println new Boolean('test') //false
```

Can anyone clarify this behavior?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Both of these

```
println 'test'.toBoolean() //false
println new Boolean('test') //false
```

instantiate a `java.lang.Boolean` using the constructor that takes a single String argument. According to [the javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#Boolean%28java.lang.String%29), the rule is:

> Allocates a Boolean object representing the value true if the string argument is not null and is equal, ignoring case, to the string "true". Otherwise, allocate a Boolean object representing the value false.

In both of the cases above, the String does not match 'true' (case-insensitively), so the Boolean created is false.

By contrast `'test' as Boolean` follows the Groovy language rules for [coercion to a boolean](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth), which allows you to write:

```
if ('hello') {
    println 'this string is truthy'
}
```

[For a String](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_strings), the rule is that if it's empty or null, it evaluates to false, otherwise true.

I agree that this could be considered a bit inconsistent, but given a choice between consistency with the constuctor of `java.lang.Boolean` and utility, I think they were right to choose the latter.

Comment: I think you meant to show the two false cases before "Both of these"

Answer (score 31):

Don is right in that:

> `'test' as Boolean` follows the Groovy language rules for [coercion to a boolean](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+Truth)

which is also known as "Groovy truth".

But `String.toBoolean()` in groovy does not just construct a Boolean with the String as an argument. From the [groovy api docs on String.toBoolean()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#toBoolean%28%29):

> `String.toBoolean()` Converts the given string into a Boolean object. If the trimmed string is "true", "y" or "1" (ignoring case) then the result is true otherwise it is false.

[A few good examples for strings and their conversion with toBoolean()](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/groovy-goodness-convert-string-to.html):

```
assert "y".toBoolean()
assert 'TRUE'.toBoolean()
assert '  trUe  '.toBoolean()
assert " y".toBoolean()
assert "1".toBoolean()

assert ! 'other'.toBoolean()
assert ! '0'.toBoolean()
assert ! 'no'.toBoolean()
assert ! '  FalSe'.toBoolean()
```

Answer (score 0):

The Boolean constructor is taking the string you gave it and running the `toBoolean()` method on that string. In a nutshell, anything it *can't parse* as a valid boolean value is treated as false. Or, in other words, only 'true' is true.

Comment: This is apparently not correct, see @jaetzold's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to agree with @cdeszaq's point about the constructor, and as far as your first example is conserned, I would say it is just casting it to a bool. As long as the pointer is not null it will be true. I imagine that `.toBoolean()` actually attempts to parse its object value. Consider executing `'true'.toBoolean()` and `'1'.toBoolean()` to see what they return.

I have never heard of Groovy before this question, this may all be incorrect.

Comment: '1'.toBoolean()​ returns true. You can test it out here: http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

However, when applied to other objects, an inconsistency arises:

```
int i = 0
String s = 'abc'

if (s)
    println 's is true' // will be printed

if (i) 
    println ' i "is true" ' // will not be printed
```

(Groovy 1.7.8)

You have to be explicit in the second if, if(i != null) or if (i != 0)

Some bugs can be traced to checking for non-null integer using if(i).

Answer (score 0):

```
 
String.metaClass.asBoolean = {
    ((String) delegate).toBoolean()
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?